# R - New column based on previous columns, for multiple similar variables

Tags: r, loops, iteration, apply

This question is similar to previous questions (based on my search) but with a twist. I hope to use [s,l,v]apply to perform this action for efficiency.

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,1,2), var1_dose_v1 = c(2,4,NA,1,NA),
             var1_dose_v2 = c(NA,NA,4,NA,3),
             var2_dose_v1 = c(NA,4,2,3,5),
             var2_dose_v2 = c(1,NA,NA,NA,NA),
             var3_dose_v1 = c(NA,NA,2,3,5),
             var3_dose_v2 = c(1,4,NA,NA,NA)))
```

Which looks like this below

```
id var1_dose_v1 var1_dose_v2 var2_dose_v1 var2_dose_v2 var3_dose_v1 var3_dose_v2
1            2           NA           NA            1           NA            1
2            4           NA            4           NA           NA            4
3           NA            4            2           NA            2           NA
1            1           NA            3           NA            3           NA
2           NA            3            5           NA            5           NA
```

I want to create a new feature that amalgamates the information from version 1 (v1) and version 2 (v2) of each var#, producing the output below.

```
id var1_dose var2_dose var3_dose
1         2          1         1
2         4          4         4
3         4          2         2
4         1          3         3
5         3          5         5
```

It's important for me to use apply since there are thousands of var#s.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This-

```
df[is.na(df)] <- 0
new_df <- sapply(seq(1:((ncol(df)-1)/2)), function(x) 
          {
           df[, paste0("var",x,"_dose_v1")] + df[, paste0("var",x,"_dose_v2")]
          })
```

Comment: What if there are 3 doses for some variables and 2 for others?

Comment: For simplicity, the solution is not generalized and restricted to the requirements posted by the question. You are right, this will not work if there are different number of versions for the doses

Answer (score 0):

```
func <- function(i){
  col <- paste0("var",i,"_dose")
  xx <- colnames(df)[grep(col, colnames(df))]
   yy <- rowSums(df[xx], na.rm = TRUE)
}
l = lapply(1:((dim(df)[2]-1)/2)  , func)

df1 = as.data.frame(l)
colnames(df1) <- paste0("var",1:((dim(df)[2]-1)/2),"_dose")

# > df1
#   var1_dose var2_dose var3_dose
# 1         2         1         1
# 2         4         4         4
# 3         4         2         2
# 4         1         3         3
# 5         3         5         5
```

---

If the 2 versions are always going to be side by side :then concised version of my code could be

```
l = lapply(1:((dim(df)[2]-1)/2), 
    function(i) rowSums(df[colnames(df)[c(i*2,i*2+1)]], na.rm = T))
df1 = as.data.frame(l)
colnames(df1) <- paste0("var",1:((dim(df)[2]-1)/2),"_dose")
```

Answer (score 0):

To have a solution that is general for any number of variables or doses, there's a new function from dplyr called 'coalesce' built for this:

```
library(dplyr)
grps <- unique(sub("_v.*$?", "", names(df)[-1]))
mat <- sapply(grps, function(g) {
  do.call("coalesce", unname(as.list(df[grep(g, names(df))])))
})
df2 <- data.frame(id=df$id, mat)
#   id var1_dose var2_dose var3_dose
# 1  1         2         1         1
# 2  2         4         4         4
# 3  3         4         2         2
# 4  1         1         3         3
# 5  2         3         5         5
```